# How to get topmost ScatterViewItem in a ScatterView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

How do I get the topmost ScatterViewItem in a ScatterView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through each of the ScatterViewitem and keep check of which ScatterViewItem.IsActive is set. that will be the topmost at that moment

For of the times it will be a loop on ScatterView.Items to iterate on ScatterViewItems

Comment: Hmm are you sure? What if I have set a ScatterViewElement to the top not by IsActive but using ScatterViewItem.setRelativeZIndex(Topmost)

Comment: Oh Sure, I was under the impression that end user making the gesture and activate one of the SVI which you want to find out. But if you set it in XAML, then ZIndex can be checked.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

`scatterView.Items.OrderBy( s => Canvas.GetZIndex(s) ).First()`